# Java: MiGLayout: How to use `hidemode`?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout, gui-design

I am starting out using [MiGLayout](http://miglayout.com/) for my GUI design, and one of the features I would need is to show/hide certain components based on the state of other components.

I was going to code this myself, when I noticed that one of the **Component Constraints** supported by MiGLayout is `hidemode`.

Does this do what I think it does? If so, how do I trigger a hide / unhide action, assuming the `hidemode` has been set? (After looking through the documentation I was able to find out how to set the `hidemode`, but not how it is used thereafter)

---

#### `hidemode`

Sets the hide mode for the component. This hide mode can be overridden by the component constraint. The hide mode specified how the layout manager should handle a component that isn't visible. The modes are:

0 - Default. Means that invisible components will be handled exactly as if they were visible.
1 - The size of the component (if invisible) will be set to 0, 0.
2 - The size of the component (if invisible) will be set to 0, 0 and the gaps will also be set to 0 around it.
3 - Invisible components will not participate in the layout at all and it will for instance not take up a grid cell.
Example: "hidemode 1"

Comment: Not exactly sure what you asking about. 
The hide mode you set defines behavior of layout for univisible (setVisible(false)) components.

Comment: @eugener So basically I still code `compXYZ.setVisible(true);` or `compXYZ.setVisible(false);`, and what `hidemode` does is define how the =other= components behave, in terms of layout, when this component's visibility is toggled?

Comment: @bquiz I actually defines how layout works with your invisible components. For example "hidemode 3" will think that your invisible component is not even part of layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mode applies when the component is [validated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#validate--), as seen in this [example](http://migcalendar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=2006). The `JFrame`'s `initGUI()` method calls `pack()`, which invokes `validate()` to do the initial layout. Later, the hideButton's `ActionListener` calls `validate()`, which recalculates the container's layout to reflect the new visibility settings. See also, [*How Layout Management Works*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/howLayoutWorks.html).

Comment: @trashgod, thanks for linking the example, it was very helpful, however, could you please elaborate on validation? I'm afraid validation wasn't in the example (or I couldn't find it)!

Answer (score 2):

MigLayout's `hidemode` is useful when you have different views, but only want to display the active one. By default, each view will occupy space in the layout, even if it isn't visible.

Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MigHidemode extends JPanel {

    private class RadioActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            final boolean showA = aRadio.isSelected();
            field.setVisible(showA);
            combo.setVisible(!showA);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

                    final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

                    final Container contentPane = dialog.getContentPane();
                    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    contentPane.add(new MigHidemode(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void windowClosed(final WindowEvent e) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    dialog.pack();
                    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private final JTextField field;
    private final JRadioButton aRadio;
    private final JRadioButton bRadio;

    private final JComboBox<String> combo;

    public MigHidemode() {
        setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[]", "[][]"));

        final RadioActionListener radioListener = new RadioActionListener();

        aRadio = new JRadioButton("A");
        aRadio.addActionListener(radioListener);
        add(aRadio, "flowx,cell 0 0");

        bRadio = new JRadioButton("B");
        bRadio.addActionListener(radioListener);
        add(bRadio, "cell 0 0");

        field = new JTextField();
        add(field, "cell 0 1,hidemode 3");
        field.setColumns(20);

        combo = new JComboBox<String>();
        combo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {
            "hello",
            "world" }));
        add(combo, "cell 0 1,hidemode 3");

        final ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(aRadio);
        bg.add(bRadio);
        aRadio.doClick();
    }
}
```