# MigLayout hidemode is not working and cannot hide component

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I have been using MigLayout for a while and i never encountered this problem. For some reason the hidemode constraint is not working and i can't make it hide a button.

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates it:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Builder extends JFrame {

    private final MigLayout migLayout = new MigLayout("debug, fillx", "[][]", "");

    public Builder() {
        try {
            createAndShowGUI();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
            Builder.this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(Builder.this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(migLayout);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("b1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("b2");
        container.add(b1, "hidemode 1, alignx left");
        container.add(b2, "alignx right");
        pack();
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("Builder");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Builder();
    }
}
```

I am using version 11.0 of MigLayout

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout-swing</artifactId>
            <version>11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you see this SO question: [Java: MiGLayout: How to use hidemode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025782/java-miglayout-how-to-use-hidemode)

Comment: Yes, but i can't find anything useful there. Is there something in my code that breaks how hidemode works?

Comment: Not sure to understand the question. `b1` is visible here, so why should it be affected by `hidemode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidemode controls *how* a component is hidden after `component.setVisible(false);` runs.  The `component.setVisible(false);` is still needed to hide the component.  Hidemode controls how surrounding components in the layout are adjusted afterward.

For example, button action listeners could be added to hide and show b1 by calling `b1.setVisible(...);`

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Builder extends JFrame {

    private final MigLayout migLayout = new MigLayout("debug, fillx", "[][]", "");

    public Builder() {
        try {
            createAndShowGUI();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
            Builder.this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(Builder.this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(migLayout);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("hide me");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("show it");
        container.add(b1, "hidemode 1, alignx left");
        container.add(b2, "alignx right");

        b1.addActionListener(e -> b1.setVisible(false));
        b2.addActionListener(e -> b1.setVisible(true));

        pack();
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("Builder");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Builder();
    }
}
```